# Cannot find OpenCV 2 Delaunay triangulation functions in OpenCV 3

Tags: c++, opencv

I have installed OpenCV 3.2.0 on Ubuntu 16 and am developing using C++ in NetBeans 8.2.  I am trying the following code which worked perfectly with OpenCV 2.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cv.hpp>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>

vector< Triangle > CTwoDTriangulation::delaunayDiv(const vector< Point_<T> > & vP, cv::Rect boundRect,
vector<Triangle>& triangles, int& numTriangles, bool lookRight)

{
CvSubdiv2D* subdiv;
int numPts=vP.size();
CvPoint newPoint;

CvMemStorage *storage;
storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
subdiv =  cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D( boundRect, storage );
for (size_t e = 0; e<numPts; e++)
{
    newPoint=vP.at(e);
    if (newPoint.x<(boundRect.x + boundRect.width) && newPoint.y<(boundRect.y + boundRect.height))
                cvSubdivDelaunay2DInsert(subdiv, vP.at(e));
}
}
```

With OpenCV 3, I get the following errors.

```
../../DraculaFiles/TwoDTriangulation.cpp:4278:60: error: there are no arguments to ‘cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D’ must be available [-fpermissive]
 subdiv =  cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D( boundRect, storage );
```

I tried typing cv:: and seeing what functions are available.  But I saw nothing similar to CreateSubdivDelaunay2D.  I have also done a Google search to see what has replaced cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D in OpenCV 3 but could not find anything.

Comment: Don't use **obsolete** C api!!!!!

Comment: Up to date link: http://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dbf/classcv_1_1Subdiv2D.html

Comment: Miki.  Useful links.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D` became legacy (so does the whole c-interface for delauny triangulation) and has been removed. 
For OpenCV 3 you can refer to the `cv::SubDiv` class instead.

Comment: That's helpful to know.  I found cv::Subdiv2D().initDelaunay(Rect rect); but it is a void function.  I could not find any functions that return type CvSubdiv2D* from cv: :Subdiv2D()  I was also unable to cast cv::Subdiv2D() to CvSubdiv2D* . Thanks,

Comment: I assume the example code under the linked duplicate may help you?

Comment: Yes it does.  Thanks,